# URL of docker container that was started from inside a docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a build machine that has several CI Build Runners running via `docker-compose` .

These runners build and test my server. In order to test my server, I have to run another `docker-compose` to start up a database and a few other mock servers (so it's docker-compose inside of docker-compose). When I run the test servers locally, I can access them via `localhost:3306` and `localhost:4000` , but that doesn't seem to work when running everything from docker inside of docker. The containers appear to be starting correctly though, but are just not accessible via `localhost`

What is the proper url that I should be calling to access those docker-compose servers from inside my docker container?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to run both containers in the same network (`workspace`).

Then, mySQL will be available as `database:3306` from your other container (`backend`).

```
version: '3'
services:
  database:
    image: database_image:latest
    container_name: database
    networks:
      - workspace
  backend_service:
    image: backend_image:latest
    container_name: backend
    networks:
      - workspace

networks:
  workspace:
    name: workspace
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: So I'm not trying to access the container inside my containers. I'm trying to access the containers from inside my server tests running inside the CI Runner docker container.

Comment: Compose provides a network named `default` for you.  You should not normally need the `networks:` blocks you show here, nor do you need `container_name:` overrides.  `database` and `backend_service` will still work as host names within this Compose file.